# Constructing an object using the genoset package in R

Tags: r

The genoset R package has a function for building a GenoSet by putting together several matrices and a RangedData object that specifies co-ordinates.

I have the following objects - three matrices, all with the same name, and a RangedData object of the following format (called locData).

```
               space                 ranges |
            <factor>              <IRanges> |
 cg00000957        1 [  5937253,   5937253] |
 cg00001349        1 [166958439, 166958439] |
 cg00001583        1 [200011786, 200011786] |
 cg00002028        1 [ 20960010,  20960010] |
 cg00002719        1 [169396706, 169396706] |
 cg00002837        1 [ 44513358,  44513358] |
```

When I try to create a GenoSet, though, I get the following error.

```
 DMRSet=GenoSet(locData,Exprs,meth,unmeth,universe=NULL)
```

Error in .Call2("IRanges_from_integer", from, PACKAGE = "IRanges") : 
  cannot create an IRanges object from an integer vector with missing values.

What am I doing wrong? all the objects I'm putting together have the same rownames, except for the IRanges object itself, which I don't think has rownames since it isn't a matrix.
Additionally, the  "column" of locData has non-integer characters.

Thank you!

Comment: Better to ask on the [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/) mailing list; the underlying problem is that some genomic coordinates (start, end) are missing (`NA`), but I don't know how your data has come to have these. `traceback()` might be your friend.

Comment: Hi Martin, the co-ordinates are all from a table containing them, and I've done a complete.cases on the original table and none of the fields in the table satisfy the is.na() condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your `"locData"` may not be a `RangedData`.  It can alternatively be a `GRanges`. Either way, you will want to name all of your arguments.

The underlying `eSet` class will be upset about that once you get past the `locData` trouble.

```
DMRSet=GenoSet(locData=locData,exprs=Exprs,meth=meth,unmeth=unmeth,universe=NULL)
```

Pete